# reading worksheet and preserving conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to read an excel worksheet with openpyxl. I think I am losing the conditional formatting information in the sheet when I read it like so:

```
xl = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
```

When I read all cells in the file and save it. I get a spreadsheet in which none of the conditional formatting is implement.

I can find many ways of adding conditional formatting to a spreadsheet at
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formatting.html

But I cannot find a way to read conditional formatting information in an existing worksheet.

The specific code I am using for doing the read and write is,

```
import openpyxl as xl

xlf = xl.load_workbook(r'd:\test\book1.xlsx')
sh = xlf.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
allcells = sh.get_cell_collection()

wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()

for c in allcells:
    row = c.row
    col = xl.cell.column_index_from_string(c.column)
    new_cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
    new_cell.value = c.value
    new_cell.style = c.style.copy()

ws.title = 'test'
wb.save(r'd:\test\book1w.xlsx')
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code of how you are reading and saving? Also, if possible can you provide a link to an example excel file? There have been issues in the past with specific attributes of conditional formatting. You may have encountered a bug or you might be saving it or reading it in such a way that it loses the conditional formatting.

Comment: ConditionalFormatting is different for each worksheet in a workbook. It may or may not include references to styles, themselves defined elswhere. As with many things in Excel files this makes copying it extremely difficult.

Comment: That's what I found too. The cf_rules had a `dfxID` but I don't know where the `dfx` rules are defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm really close, but I can't get the color to stay. There is still an error, but at least the following does add keep conditional formatting rules if not the fill choice:

```
for range_string in sh.conditional_formatting.cf_rules:
    for cfRule in sh.conditional_formatting.cf_rules[range_string]:
        ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_string, cfRule)
```

The same is achieved with this one liner (but same end result):

```
ws.conditional_formatting.update(sh.conditional_formatting.cf_rules)
```

Now if you open up `Manage Rules` in excel the rules are all there, but when you open the file it requires automatic repairing and I lose the color. Here's the super helpful log (sarcasm intended here):

```
<repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml</repairedRecord></repairedRecords>
```

I got similar results when I tried to copy `conditional_formatting`'s three attributes directly like so:

```
ws.conditional_formatting.cf_rules = sh.conditional_formatting.cf_rules.copy()
ws.conditional_formatting.max_priority = sh.conditional_formatting.max_priority
ws.conditional_formatting.parse_rules = sh.conditional_formatting.parse_rules.copy()
```

I've been looking at the [source code](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/formatting.html#ConditionalFormatting) for ideas.

**EDIT**

There is one really easy alternative. Don't create a brand new workbook and worksheet and work on them from scratch. Just modify the original as needed and then save it as a different name. Or you could even start by saving it as a different name to create a copy, then modify the copy. This will preserve all formatting rules.

Comment: This looks like it might get pretty close. But you'll need to compare the generated files using the MS Office OpenXML Productivity Tool to see what's missing or different. Suffice it to say that copying parts of Excel files is rarely as easy as it seems. Your suggestion of saving under a new name is indeed the best approach.